# Move some line of codes inside with() function in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

For simplify reason, could I move some line of codes inside with() function like below?

```
// from this
val params: RelativeLayout.LayoutParams = RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(MATCH_PARENT, WRAP_CONTENT)
params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP)
textView.layoutParams = params
// to this inside with()
textView.layoutParams = with() {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do.

```
with(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(MATCH_PARENT, WRAP_CONTENT)){
    addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP)
    textView.layoutParams = this
}
```

or,

```
textView.layoutParams = with(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(MATCH_PARENT, WRAP_CONTENT)){
    addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP)
    this
}
```

or,

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(MATCH_PARENT, WRAP_CONTENT).apply {
    addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP)
    textView.layoutParams = this
}
```

or,

```
textView.layoutParams = RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(MATCH_PARENT, WRAP_CONTENT).apply {
    addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP)
}
```